# Cannot clone repository with bitbucket and Github...Java

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket

Im using eclipse Luna, when I use the "git clone url", it gets the files and all from the repository, but, when I Import the project, It don't says the " master", and I can't make pull or anything related :(. What's wrong?

Comment: Maybe you don't have a Git plugin for Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, when you import the project, you select "copy into the workspace", then you will get a copy of the sources from the git repo you just cloned.
That means those files aren't in a Git repo anymore (they are in your Eclipse workspace).

But if you import the project *without* selecting that option, the the files remains in the Git repo, and the Git options should be present.

Comment: I'm still having problems, that option is not marked, but I still don't let me make pulls or push

Comment: @nanokuro then try sharing your imported project: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Sharing or http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html#multiprojects_add